# displaying checkmark in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a gridview and a datsource. There is one column in datasource that I want to interpret and display a checkmark if it is a certain value (text). [My question is similar to this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_24042436.html). Is it doable? Note: If I add image field in gridview it tries to bind to an image url in the database which is not the case for me. I dont want to change the database, just display a checkmark in the gridview.

[image] <- Edit: included an image to differentiate from checkbox.

Comment: I guess I have to add template field and add an image link in item template.

Comment: Is a template field so undesirable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (answering myself). This is my template field (showing only relevent code)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" >
<HeaderTemplate> </HeaderTemplate> 
<ItemTemplate>        // all other templates removed
<asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/checkmark_s.png" runat="server" Visible=<%#  showImageIfCalled((string)Eval("isCalled")) %> />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the function that returns either true or false

```
protected bool showImageIfCalled(string val)
    {
        if (val == "called")
           return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Notice that I am not using 'single quotes or "double quotes" in front of Visible = field

Answer (score 1):

insert a template column to your Grid view columns:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Edit:for the checkmark

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# GetCheckMark(Eval("Checked")) %>' ID="imgCheckMark" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

in the codebehind

```
protected string GetCheckMark(bool checked){
  return checked?"~/images/checkmark.gif":"~/images/uncheckmark.gif";
}
```

and thats it :)

Comment: you can use this jquery plugin to convert the checkboxes into checkmarks http://jqidealforms.com/

Comment: this worked well for me although "checked" is a C# keyword and needs to be changed to something else.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will helps you how to put the check box inside the grid view

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CheckBoxExample.aspx.cs" Inherits="CheckBoxExample" %>
```

```
<title>CheckBox Example</title>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="ProductGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ItemId">
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemDescription" DataFormatString="{0}" HeaderText="Item" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemPrice" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Price" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Purchase">

               <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPurchase" runat="server" Enabled="true" />
               </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Button ID="Purchase" runat="server" Text="Purchase Checked Items" />

</div>

</form>
```

Comment: sorry the question is asking for checkmark, not checkbox. I am on the right track but need to call a function from the templatefield and pass the value of field so I can return true or false from the function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you were binding to a boolean column in the data source, you could add a `CheckBoxField` to the GridView's columns and this would display what you require.

But it sounds like you want to check the box based on a text column. One way you could get around this is by adding a boolean column to the data source once you've retrieved it, and manually setting this field for each row based on the text field.

I hope this makes sense.